# Why can I pass by value here but not by reference (C++)?

Tags: c++, class, templates, readonly

I have an interesting predicament here where the code will compile if I pass a variable by value to the function but not if I pass it by reference, and I'm not sure why.  In header.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void get_name(std::string &name)
{
  getline(std::cin, name);
  return;
}

template <class T, class U>
class readonly
{
  friend U;
  private:
    T data;
    T& operator=(const T& arg) {data = arg; return data;}
  public:
    operator const T&() const {return data;}
};

class myClass
{
  private:
    typedef readonly<std::string, myClass> RO_string;

  public:
    RO_string y;

    void f()
    {
      get_name(y); // compile error
    }
};
```

The main.cpp implementation file simply includes this header file, creates an instance of `myClass` and then calls `f()`.  When doing so, it won't compile properly.  The problem lies in the fact that I'm passing the variable `y` by reference to the `get_name` function.  If I change the function so that I pass by value instead, everything compiles properly and works as expected (except I'm obviously not making changes to `y` anymore).  However, I don't understand this behavior.  **Why does this happen and is there an optimal way to fix it in this situation?**

Comment: A `readonly` class? Interesting. It is unnecessary but self-explaining at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conversion operator:

```
operator const T&() const {return data;}
```

Only allows implicit conversion to a const reference. This makes sense since you are interested in making something read only. But `get_name` requires a non-const reference to a string. That is, `get_name` expects to be able to mutate its input. The type being passed in cannot convert to a mutable string reference, only to a constant string reference, so it doesn't compile.

When you pass by value, it simply constructs a new string from the const reference to pass into the function, which is fine.

Intuitively, a function called `get_name` should probably take a const reference since it shouldn't need to mutate its input just to get the name.

Comment: Intuitively, a function called `get_name` should use a return value instead of an output parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by Nir Friedman, `get_name(y);` invoques the implicit conversion operator which gives you a const reference.

But, as you wrote `friend U;`, `myClass` has access to the private member `data` of `y` and allows you to do:

```
get_name(y.data);
```